# Type '() => Observable<any>' is not assignable to type '() => Observable<any>'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, static, public

I'm making an ionic 2 app using typescript and after upgrading the local typescript installation to version `2.2.1` from version `2.1.0` I have started receiving this error:

> Type '() => Observable' is not assignable to type '() =>
>   Observable'. Two different types with 
>               this name exist, but they are unrelated. Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'. 
>               Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.

This error repeats for each of the following lines

```
L28:  this.onDisconnect = Network.onDisconnect
L29:  this.onchange = Network.onchange
L30:  this.ontypechange = Network.ontypechange
```

`Network` is a class imported from `ionic-native` its `onDisconnect`, `onchange` and `ontypechange` methods are defined as follow:

```
static onDisconnect(): Observable<any>;
static onchange(): Observable<any>;
static ontypechange(): Observable<any>;
```

I have `onDisconnect`, `onchange`, and `ontypechange` as `public` properties of a custom class (`@Injectable()` class) called "Network" and I have defined them as follows:

```
L15:  public onDisconnect: ()=>Observable<any>
L16:  public ontypechange: ()=>Observable<any>
L17:  public onchange: ()=>Observable<any>
```

I have three questions?

**First:** Would someone help me understand what the error really means in typescript and why it occurs as such in my code.

**Second:** While I do know I could just extend the class, I do not want to do it. So I am asking, does the difference in declaring my methods as `public` while the ones in the class are `static` cause this problem?

**Third:** what's the difference of these two kinds of defining a property on a class?

EDIT:

I just realized that I had previously tried extending the Network class and this failed due to the static declaration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two different versions of rxjs lurking in your `node_modules` tree, and TS does not know that they are the "same".

The first thing to try would be to clear your entire `node_modules` directory, flush the npm cache, and redo `npm install`.

If that does not solve the problem, the underlying issue is likely to be that different dependencies have specified rxjs versions which are incompatible, forcing npm to bring in a separate version of rxjs for one or more of them (which it will place in the `node_modules` directory **under** some module). You will see a structure such as

```
node_modules
  dependencyA
  rxjs
  dependencyB
    node_modules
      rxjs
```

If this is what is happening, then you will have no option but to track down the offending version requirement. For instance, the top level `package.json` may have `rxjs: "^5.2.0"`, whereas `dependencyB/package.json` may have `rxjs: "5.0.0"`.

Comment: trying this now. Are you saying that there is nothing wrong with how I have made my code? And how would I do what you are suggesting? `npm prune`? Plus my package,json has `"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12"`

Comment: No, there should be nothing wrong with your code. To clean `node_modules`, run `rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean` or the equivalent in your OS. Try replacing the dependency in your `package.json` with `"rxjs": "^5.0.0"`. Versions with `beta` in their name do not play well with the semver matching strategy. If all else fails, you can try something like `"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12 || >=5.0.0"`.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I think it's a typescript related affair. Started right after upgrading the global typescript

Comment: reverting to typescript v2.0.9 as had been before solved my problem. But this still begs the question, Whats wrong with my typing?

Comment: If 2.0.9 works and 2.2.1 doesn't, definitely file an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript to let the team know asap.

Comment: It's essentially unthinkable that this is a TS bug. It's almost certainly some kind of version conflict caused by new type libraries brought in by the new version of TS.

Comment: It is definitely a version conflict, after removing (`rm -Rf node_modules`) and reinstalling all node_modules (`npm i`) everything works fine. I'm therefore accepting this as the correct answer. It would however be great to get an explanation for the meaning of this error from a typescript point of view

Comment: This may be fixed in TS2.5.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Changing `import { Observable }` from `rxjs/observable` to `import { Observable }` from `rxjs`;

Comment: I'll sure try this

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. It will increase the bundle size of your production build drastically.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error as a result of incompatibility between RxJS and Ngrx v7 in a certain version. Downgrading RxJS to ~6.4.0 helped. I ran `yarn add rxjs@~6.4.0` worked for me and the error was resolved.